# Mailto Hyperlink Limitations?

Tags: html, vba

I am attempting to create a VBA Macro that will automatically send emails based on attributes within my spreadsheet - within each email is HTML code with <a href ="mailto:...> hyperlinks. The cc and bcc fields in those hyperlinks are dynamic as well.

I create the HTML code for the hyperlinks within the excel spreadsheet itself by using Concatenate to create the following values:

```
<a href=" mailto:toemail1@fake.com?cc=ccemail1@fake.com&bcc=bccemail1@fake.com&subject=subjectext&body=emailbody">send email</a>
```

In order to test that it works, I display the olmailitem before sending. All of my hyperlinks work perfectly when the olmailitem is displayed. However, when I send the email to myself to test it from my Outlook, one of the hyperlinks fails to open. There is no error message - it just does not open.

The one difference between the mailto hyperlink that does not work and the others is that there are around 70 emails that are BCC'ed in the html. The length of this mailto hyperlink is 1683 characters.

I think that my issue is that there is a maximum length to a URL that outlook can handle from its desktop application. However, I don't know what that length is. Does anyone have insight?

Comment: Seems like this could easily be determined by creating a series of different-length URL's?  I see references to a 1024-character limit but that was for Outlook 2007....

Comment: Thank you again, Tim! I think the 1024 character limit build is correct. Now I just need to find a work around when the hyperlink is more than 1024 Characters, and I am sure there are no shortage of options.